# PHP 5.3: Using __autoload() to instantiate a class inside another class

Tags: php, oop, autoload, composition

I'm reasonably green with OOP, and I can't quite intuit how composition and `__autoload()` are supposed to work together. What I'm currently trying to build is a class which will have as it's properties quite a number of other classes. To give some context, this particular app lends support to an indie role-playing game that is being developed simultaneously.

The basic file structure goes:

localhost/project/

- index.php
- lib/

localhost/project/lib

- common.php
- class/

localhost/project/lib/class

- Character.php
- SkillSet.php
- Equipment.php

And so on. In `index.php` I have:

```
<?php 
require_once("lib/common.php"); 
// ...bunch of bootstrapping and what not...
$char = new Character;
?>
```

Then in `common.php`:

```
<?php
define("DS", "/");
define("SER", "localhost");
define("BASE", "project");
define("LIB", "lib");
define("CLS", "class");

function __autoload($class_name) {
    include CLS.DS.$class_name . ".php";
}
```

Finally, the main class, `Character`, opens with:

```
<?php

class Character {
    // properties
    public $skills      = new SkillSet;


    public function character() {
    //init
    }
}
?>
```

When I run this, I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in...` from Character, but I'm not clear on why. By the time the call to assign `$char` is made, `common.php` has been loaded, which means `__autoload()` is available, and indeed it finds `Character`.

**My questions:**
a) Why does `__autoload()` not work inside a class, and
b) How is composition *supposed* to be done in object-oriented PHP?

Help most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax error has nothing to do with autoloading. You simply cannot create that class at this point in the code (this is not Java). You can only assign static values of scalars as the initial value of properties.

If you want that property to be initialized with another class, assign it inside the `__construct()` function.

Regarding composition: Use depencency injection. Allow the outside world to pass the class to be used, instead of creating it inside that class.

Comment: a) Thanks, I hadn't realized I couldn't do that re: assignment and b) just to make sure I'm following, you're suggesting I instantiate a `SkillSet` class in, say, `index.php` and then pass it to `Character`, is that right? There isn't a way to `__autoload()` from inside a class?

Comment: NVM; the `__autoload()` in `common.php` works just fine as soon as I do the assignment in the constructor as per your advice, thanks so much!